# React: Invoking function with parameters causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

## **So, I have a component that renders another component with a prop like so:**

```
`<Component_One>
    <Component_Two onChange={this.changeSomething} />
</Component_One>`
```

#### Inside Component_One, the function `changeSomething()` takes one parameter: `id`

So inside `Component_One`, `changeSomething()` looks like this:

```
`changeSomething(id) {
    this.setState({something: id});
}`
```

### **`Component_Two` looks like this:**

```
`<div id="componenttwo">
    <div onClick={this.props.onChange(0)}>
        <div className="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div onClick={this.props.onChange(1)}>
        <div className="badge"></div>
    </div>
    <div onClick={this.props.onChange(2)}>
        <div className="badge"></div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

The object is to get `this.state.something` inside `Component_One` to equal the explicitly typed `id` of the div in `Component_Two`...

but instead it throws this error: `SCRIPT5022: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

So how do I pass an explicitly typed argument to a "prop function" without creating an infinite loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should pass a function to `onClick` handler but you are calling the function. Because of that the function is called immediately and set the `state` which causes rerender, resulting in infinite loop. Pass a function instead like

```
onClick={() => this.props.onChange(0)}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you so much! I had no clue what I was doing wrong! :D I can't mark it as the answer for another 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access parameter in component one:

```
<Component_Two onChange={(id) => this.changeSomething(id)} />
```

Now calling `this.props.onChange(0)` will pass 0 as a value for id.

Comment: Thank you so much! Note that the onClick event handler in `Component_Two` must receive a function instead of invoking a function as well. See Prakash sharma's answer.

Comment: Agreed. So, the correct answer should consist both mine and Prakash answer. Isn't it?

Comment: Actually, Prakash's solution is all you need! Using an anonymous function inside the prop on Component_Two inside Component_One doesn't break the code, but it works without it. I honestly don't know enough about props to tell you why that is but changing the invoked function in Component_Two to be an anonymous function instead of a function call fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

change your `changeSomething` function like this:

```
const changeSomething = (id) => (event) => {
    this.setState({something: id});
}
```